# ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

Tags: python, pandas

Como va comunidad? estoy teniendo un problema que no logro entender bien y ya lei mucho y no logro solucionarlo de ninguna manera, tengo el siguiente TXT(son dos pero son cuasi identicos):

```
Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
BE1                up          up          ENLACE A R1
BE2                up          up          ENLACE A R2
BE3                up          up          a R3
Lo10               up          up          
Lo20               admin-down  admin-down  
Lo22               up          up          Loopback para pruebas
Lo69               admin-down  admin-down  
Lo99               admin-down  admin-down  
Lo100              up          up          Prueba
Gi0/3/4/0          up          up          asdsad
Gi0/3/4/0.26       up          up          asdasdsad
Gi0/3/4/0.78       up          up          Servers_10-0-78-0
Gi0/3/4/0.100      up          up          VLAN100
Gi0/3/4/0.180      admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/3/4/0.223      admin-down  admin-down  PRUEBA TUNEL IPSEC
Gi0/3/4/0.416      up          up          Servers_10-204-216
Gi0/3/4/0.773      up          up          Gestion_10-0-69-0
Gi0/3/4/0.777      admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/3/4/1          up          up          ENLACE A r11
Gi0/3/4/1.3098     up          up          Frontera MP-eBGP con r4
Gi0/3/4/2          up          up          ENLACE A r7
Gi0/3/4/2.201      up          up          Frontera Cliente A
Gi0/3/4/2.202      up          up          Frontera Cliente B
Gi0/3/4/2.203      up          up          Frontera Cliente C
Gi0/3/4/3          up          up          ENLACE A R9
Gi0/3/4/3.401      up          up          Frontera Cliente A
Gi0/3/4/3.402      up          up          Frontera Cliente B
Gi0/3/4/3.403      up          up          Frontera Cliente C
```

Lo reuje bastante ya que son como 170 lineas pero se entiende.

y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
from dataclasses import replace
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from datetime import datetime
import re
from pathlib import Path
import os
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from sympy import Line2D

ruta = Path("E:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M Real\Archivos")

def is_free(valor):
    color = 'green' if valor == "free"  else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

list_txt = [ruta/"FRI01.txt", ruta/"FRU01.txt"]

for txt in list_txt:

  host = txt.stem

  sheet_name=f'{host}-Gi0-3-4-2'

  ruta_host = ruta/'ejemplo.xlsx'

  df = pd.read_fwf(txt)

  df["Description"] = (df.iloc[:, 3:].fillna("").astype(str).apply(" ".join, axis=1).str.strip())

  df = df.iloc[:, :4]

  df = df.drop(columns = ["Status", "Protocol"])

  df.Interface = df.Interface.str.extract('Gi0/3/4/2\.(\d+)')

  df = df[df.Interface.notnull()].reset_index()

  df = df.drop(columns = ["index"])

  df['Interface'] = df['Interface'].astype(int)

  print(df)

  df = df.set_index('Interface').reindex(range(1,3580), ).fillna('free').reset_index()

  print(df)
  #df = df.style.applymap(is_free)

  if not ruta_host.exists():
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(ruta_host)
    writer.close()            
  else:
    pass  

  with pd.ExcelWriter(ruta_host, mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:

    df = df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False)


wb = load_workbook(ruta_host)
if 'Sheet1' in wb.sheetnames:
  wb.remove(wb['Sheet1'])
  wb.save(ruta_host)
else:
  pass
```

y me arroja el suguiente error:

```
e:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M\Pruebas3.py:45: FutureWarning: reindexing with a non-unique Index is deprecated and will raise in a future version.
  df = df.set_index('Interface').reindex(range(1,3580), ).fillna('free').reset_index()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M\Pruebas3.py", line 45, in <module>
    df = df.set_index('Interface').reindex(range(1,3580), ).fillna('free').reset_index()
  File "E:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 324, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4804, in reindex
    return super().reindex(**kwargs)
  File "E:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4966, in reindex
    return self._reindex_axes(
  File "E:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4623, in _reindex_axes
    frame = frame._reindex_index(
  File "E:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4642, in _reindex_index
    return self._reindex_with_indexers(
  File "E:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5032, in _reindex_with_indexers
    new_data = new_data.reindex_indexer(
  File "E:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 679, in reindex_indexer
    self.axes[axis]._validate_can_reindex(indexer)
  File "E:\Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4107, in _validate_can_reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels")
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

Haciendo diferentes pruebas para probar posibles fallos fue, primero q nada si en `list_txt` quito un elemento de la lista y ya no aparece ese error, por otra parte si entro a los TXT y les quito algunas lineas al azar deja de aparecer el error por lo q me confunde bastante, no se si aclara pero ambos TXT tiene diferentes cantidades de lineas.

haciendo un breve resumen lo q se hace es tomar todas las interfaces "Gi0/3/4/2.xxx" quitar el "Gi0/3/4/2" y dejar solo el numero posterior al punto es decir "201" por lo que quedan varios numeros en la columna y se completa la lista hasta 3580 y los numeros que no estaban en el txt inicial se les coloca una descripcion "free" quedando asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de lo que esta pasando o como solucionarlo?

Comment: La columna `Interface` que deseas utilizar como índice parece tener duplicados, eso es lo que te está indicando, que no es posible utilizar `reindex` en una serie con duplicados

Comment: Como estas HeytalePazguato? muchas gracias por el aporte. Bueno segun lo que estuve leyendo y pude entender es que si, posiblemente sea ese el problema, el tema es que si bien lo estoy usando dos veces la columna `Interface` lo estoy haciendo en 2 hojas distintas del mismo libro, y lo extraño es que si recorto el numero de lineas de cada TXT no me arroja ese error y ahi es como que pierde un poco de coherencia el error y me confunde.